# How i could cut exactly frames from an avi with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I use the command below to cut it to frames. I want 48 frames for my video which is 7 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -i output.avi -r 6.4 -s sxga images\\image%d.jpeg
```

It creates me the frames but i was use it with different videos and it gives me different results. The output.avi is 7 seconds but it gives me 46 - 50 frames depending for the output video which I insert.

The output of command line for the first video is :

```
>ffmpeg -i "only7s.avi" -r 6.4 -s sxga images\\image%d.jpeg
ffmpeg version N-62121-g634636e Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  3 2014 23:30:16 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 73.100 / 52. 73.100
  libavcodec     55. 56.107 / 55. 56.107
  libavformat    55. 36.101 / 55. 36.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'only7s.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.101
  Duration: 00:00:07.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4890 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1024x768, 4924
 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 59.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 1
28 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0358bec0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'images\\image%d.jpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1024, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 6
.40 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
*** dropping frame 8 from stream 0 at ts 5
*** dropping frame 9 from stream 0 at ts 6
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 10 from stream 0 at ts 7
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=22.7 size=N/A time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=9
*** dropping frame 11 from stream 0 at ts 8
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 12 from stream 0 at ts 9
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 13 from stream 0 at ts 10
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 14 from stream 0 at ts 11
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 15 from stream 0 at ts 12
*** dropping frame 16 from stream 0 at ts 13
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 17 from stream 0 at ts 14
*** dropping frame 18 from stream 0 at ts 15
frame=   19 fps= 18 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=27
*** dropping frame 19 from stream 0 at ts 16
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 20 from stream 0 at ts 17
*** dropping frame 21 from stream 0 at ts 18
*** dropping frame 22 from stream 0 at ts 19
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 23 from stream 0 at ts 20
*** dropping frame 24 from stream 0 at ts 21
frame=   24 fps= 15 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:03.75 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=35
*** dropping frame 25 from stream 0 at ts 22
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 26 from stream 0 at ts 23
*** dropping frame 27 from stream 0 at ts 24
*** dropping frame 28 from stream 0 at ts 25
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 29 from stream 0 at ts 26
*** dropping frame 30 from stream 0 at ts 27
*** dropping frame 31 from stream 0 at ts 28
frame=   31 fps= 15 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:04.84 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=44
*** dropping frame 31 from stream 0 at ts 28
*** dropping frame 32 from stream 0 at ts 29
*** dropping frame 33 from stream 0 at ts 30
*** dropping frame 34 from stream 0 at ts 31
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 35 from stream 0 at ts 32
*** dropping frame 36 from stream 0 at ts 33
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=   37 fps= 14 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:05.78 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=52
*** dropping frame 37 from stream 0 at ts 34
*** dropping frame 38 from stream 0 at ts 35
*** dropping frame 39 from stream 0 at ts 36
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 40 from stream 0 at ts 37
*** dropping frame 41 from stream 0 at ts 38
*** dropping frame 42 from stream 0 at ts 39
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=   43 fps= 14 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:06.71 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=60
*** dropping frame 43 from stream 0 at ts 40
*** dropping frame 44 from stream 0 at ts 41
*** dropping frame 45 from stream 0 at ts 42
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 46 from stream 0 at ts 43
*** dropping frame 47 from stream 0 at ts 44
frame=   47 fps= 13 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:07.34 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=66

video:2537kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 709977824034816.000000%
```

The output of command line for the second video is :

```
>ffmpeg -i "C:\ArtWedding\bin\x86\Debug\flipvideo\video180327.avi" -r 6.4 -s sxg
a images\\image%d.jpeg
ffmpeg version N-62121-g634636e Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  3 2014 23:30:16 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 73.100 / 52. 73.100
  libavcodec     55. 56.107 / 55. 56.107
  libavformat    55. 36.101 / 55. 36.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\ArtWedding\bin\x86\Debug\flipvideo\video180327.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.101
  Duration: 00:00:07.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128364 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 640x480, 128928 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 3
0 tbc
[swscaler @ 029adf40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'images\\image%d.jpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 1280x1024, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 6
.40 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
*** dropping frame 10 from stream 0 at ts 7
frame=   10 fps=0.0 q=19.9 size=N/A time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=1
*** dropping frame 10 from stream 0 at ts 7
*** dropping frame 11 from stream 0 at ts 8
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 12 from stream 0 at ts 9
*** dropping frame 13 from stream 0 at ts 10
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 14 from stream 0 at ts 11
*** dropping frame 15 from stream 0 at ts 12
frame=   16 fps= 16 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:02.50 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=10
*** dropping frame 16 from stream 0 at ts 13
*** dropping frame 17 from stream 0 at ts 14
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 18 from stream 0 at ts 15
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 19 from stream 0 at ts 16
*** dropping frame 21 from stream 0 at ts 18
frame=   21 fps= 14 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=20
*** dropping frame 23 from stream 0 at ts 20
*** dropping frame 24 from stream 0 at ts 21
*** dropping frame 25 from stream 0 at ts 22
*** dropping frame 27 from stream 0 at ts 24
frame=   28 fps= 14 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:04.37 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=24
*** dropping frame 29 from stream 0 at ts 26
*** dropping frame 31 from stream 0 at ts 28
*** dropping frame 33 from stream 0 at ts 30
*** dropping frame 34 from stream 0 at ts 31
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=   34 fps= 13 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:05.31 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=30
*** dropping frame 35 from stream 0 at ts 32
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 36 from stream 0 at ts 33
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 37 from stream 0 at ts 34
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 38 from stream 0 at ts 35
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=   39 fps= 13 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:06.09 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=43
*** dropping frame 39 from stream 0 at ts 36
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 40 from stream 0 at ts 37
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 41 from stream 0 at ts 38
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 42 from stream 0 at ts 39
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** dropping frame 43 from stream 0 at ts 40
frame=   43 fps= 12 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:06.71 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=56
*** dropping frame 44 from stream 0 at ts 41
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 45 from stream 0 at ts 42
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 46 from stream 0 at ts 43
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 47 from stream 0 at ts 44
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=   47 fps= 11 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:07.34 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=70
*** dropping frame 48 from stream 0 at ts 45
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 49 from stream 0 at ts 46
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** dropping frame 50 from stream 0 at ts 47
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=   50 fps= 11 q=24.8 size=N/A time=00:00:07.81 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=78
*** dropping frame 50 from stream 0 at ts 47
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=   51 fps= 11 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=80

video:4415kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 407988875558912.000000%
```

Comment: Please also include the full command line outputs for two different cases. If you have a video sample that would be even better.

Comment: i edit it. and i wrote the results from both of videos.

Comment: One is 7.04 seconds and the other is 07.47 seconds. Of course you will get different numbers of frames as output. If you want ffmpeg to write a specific number of frames, add the `-frames:v 48` option, for example. Does that achieve what you need?

Comment: Only at second one. At first one which create 47 frames. It doesn't create 48.

Comment: Because the 47th frame is already beyond the total duration, so there is no 48th frame it could create. You might need to use another framerate in this case so as to be able to "stretch" it.

Comment: Yes i know that but i am trying to create a command for wholes my video which is between 7.00 to 7.59 seconds. if i change framerate for the first video it will cut out last milliseconds of second video for example.